# Rails OpenSSL encryption/decryption?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption, cryptography

Inherited ruby codebase which uses attr_encrypted gem to encrypt attributes.

I want to decrypt values and encrypt them. Simple task!

Decryption works.

Encrypting back again doesn't work?

Here's code to decrypt:

```
Encryptor.decrypt(Base64.decode64("mbgtmCefo8NZOWrSmrq0frYpMR8nRFRz83CkX7VqxAs="), :key=>'95f94bbd12fb60c156aea0c5fead8498b10cff780624b064a98d9aefa74e6a43b2cf7bfb4d0ab5fa44541b5e5385ccf0ef0e1bb563a6ea618f14c2770b583ba')
 => "4763671098237511"
```

Here's code to encrypt:

```
Encryptor.encrypt(Base64.encode64("4763671098237511"), :key=>'95f94bbd12fb60c156aea0c5fead8498b10cff780624b064a98d9aefa74e6a43b2cf7bfb4d0ab5fa44541b5e5385ccf0ef0e1bb563a6ea618f14c2770b583ba')
 => "\xC7\xB4\xEB\xE8d\x11l\xB2\xC3\xCDd8\x1E\x88\xDD\xF3\x93\x96H6*\xD2!\f\x9C%F\x14\xE7\xC7\xF3\x1F"
```

Code I was expecting:

```
"mbgtmCefo8NZOWrSmrq0frYpMR8nRFRz83CkX7VqxAs="
```

Can someone clarify this issue?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should encrypt plaintext to create ciphertext, and then decrypt the ciphertext so you can retrieve the plaintext again. Decrypting plaintext will give you random garbage, as it expects input as created by the encrypt method. Encrypting for instance should also store an IV and pad the plaintext.

So first encrypt, then decrypt, not the other way around. Decryption and then encryption works for some cipher modes, but it certainly won't work for a higher level function that uses the CBC mode of operation.